# How to change password hashing algorithm when using spring security?

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm working on a legacy Spring MVC based web Application which is using a - by current standards - inappropriate hashing algorithm. Now I want to gradually migrate all hashes to bcrypt. My high level strategy is:

- New hashes are generated with bcrypt by default
- When a user successfully logs in and has still a legacy hash, the app replaces the old hash with a new bcrypt hash.

What is the most idiomatic way of implementing this strategy with Spring Security? Should I use a custom Filter or my on AccessDecisionManager or …?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll probably have to customize your `AuthenticationProvider` since that is where the password is actually compared with the user data and you have all the information you need available.

In the `authenticate` method, you would first load the user data. Then check the user-supplied password with both a `BCryptPasswordEncoder` and your legacy one. If neither returns a match, throw a `BadCredentialsException`.

If the user authenticates successfully (very important :-)) and the password is legacy format (the legacy encoder matched), you would then call some additional code to update the user's account data and replace the legacy hash with a bcrypt one. The `BCryptPasswordEncoder` can be also be used to create new hashes.

If you want, you could detect in advance whether the stored hash was already bcrypt before doing the comparisons. Bcrypt strings have quite a distinct format.

Note also that to make it harder to guess valid account names, you should try to make the method behave the same both when a supplied username exists and when it doesn't (in terms of the time it takes). So call the encoders even when you don't have any user data for the supplied username.

Answer (score 0):

i think best way to do this is to specify password encoder to authentication provider some thing like below, for more information refer [doc](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-password-encoder)

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
        <password-encoder ref="passwordEncoder">
            <salt-source ref="saltSource" />
        </password-encoder>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>


<beans:bean     class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.Md5PasswordEncoder"
    id="passwordEncoder" />

<beans:bean     class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource"
    id="saltSource">
    <beans:property name="userPropertyToUse" value="userName" />
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. It is asking how to migrate an existing app using a legacy hash format to one using bcrypt.