# Convert password hashing from SHA to bcrypt

Tags: grails, spring-security, bcrypt, jbcrypt

This questions has been answered in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13762772/how-to-change-password-hashing-algorithm-when-using-spring-security) already, but it's not Grails-specific and is also kind of vague.

I set my Grails app up with Spring Security, but apparently didn't get the newest version, because it defaulted to SHA-256 instead of bcrypt.  Now I have production data with passwords hashed in what seems to be a less-than-ideal method.

It's a piece of cake to *enable* bcrypt hashing:

```
Config.groovy > grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.algorithm = 'bcrypt'
```

but now I need the app to convert the old hashes into new ones. Fundamentally, I understand that when a user logs in, I should have the app check to see if the password is an SHA-256 hash, and if so, re-hash the entered password with bcrypt. After a while, they'll all be upgraded and that code can be removed.

What is the actual code for determining if a password hash is from SHA-256 or bcrypt, though?

**EDIT**

That is to say, what is the actual function that I call to get a hash?  How do I `bcrypt(incomingpassword)` to see if it matches the existing password hash?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

bcrypt passwords will start with "$2a$10$" and be 60 chars long. There is no pattern for SHA-256, but it will be 64 chars long.

Comment: Thanks, Burt. I still have the same problem, though; I have no idea how to instantiate and call an arbitrary password encoder at will. I have dug into Spring Security's internals, but it quickly gets beyond my ability to understand at this point.  If I want to go `user.hashedPassword == bcrypt(incomingPassword)`... what do I actually type instead of "bcrypt"?

Comment: I thought this was interesting and good to have documented, so I worked up an implementation and blog post here: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2017

Comment: Hmm.  `Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No such algorithm [bcrypt]`  I'm running Grails 2.2.0 and the Spring Security plugin 2.0-RC2.

Comment: Use the settings for SHA-256 or whatever the old algorithm is - the bcrypt encoder is explicitly configured. Once you're ready to switch to a single algorithm, remove all of this and configure bcrypt like in a new app

Comment: Say... is it possible that the SHA-256 implementation has changed between Spring Security Plugin version 1 and version 2?  Because `sha256PasswordEncoder` is not hashing my password into the same hash as what's in the database.

Comment: Actually, SSP 2.0-RC2 defaults to bcrypt. That's what was causing the exception above. I'm pretty confident of this because I just uninstalled and reinstalled it the plugin.  Setting the algorithm to 'SHA-256' in my config got rid of the exception.  It's still not hashing the password correctly, though. http://www.convertstring.com/Hash/SHA256 encodes my password to the same thing that's in my DB.  sha256PasswordEncoder.encodePassword does not.

Comment: You probably need `grails.plugin.springsecurity.password.hash.iterations = 1` also, since the 1.2 plugin used 1 iteration and the 2.0 plugin defaults to 10,000

Comment: That did it. Forgot to check that when I was looking back at 1.2. Thanks.

Comment: Does spring security understand this format of hash?  The example passwords in the documentation at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-password-encoder are in a different format...?

Comment: This is Spring Security, just a Grails-y wrapper around it. I'm not sure what's up with those docs, but the passwords are not bcrypt hashes.